# Texture in a Triangle

Tags: ios, metal, metalkit

Is it possible to do texturing inside 3 Vertex(Triangle). I drawing a triangle. I want to read the previous pixel inside fragment shader inside triangular area using sampler and I want to color. If there is previous color available i need to clear color. If color is available I need to add color to the pixel.

Inside quad we can do it sampling the texture.

Comment: Sounds like a form of blending.  I don't see how the shape of the geometry will make a difference, as long as the UV (tex-coords) make sense.

Comment: Metal doesn't have direct support for quads. If you're drawing and texturing a quad, you're already drawing and texturing triangles.